# Route whole PC traffic from organization (University) given proxy server

Tags: networking, proxy

There is an option in **Setting=> Proxy => Manual Proxy setup**, using this we can route our traffic to the proxy server. But the problem with the approach is that we can only transfer the browser traffic, not all PC traffic. For example, I have set up my proxy server like below image.

[image]

My browsers (Firefox, Chrome) are working fine but my desktop application like "**WeChat**" says there is no internet.
[image]
OneDrive is also not working.

**Is there any utility software or other way to do this task?**

Comment: I think you need to set up a SOCKS v5 Proxy server for this.

Answer (score 1):

The Settings app can only do simple proxies, but for passing all the traffic
for all protocols, not only TCP, you need to use a
[Socks5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS5)
proxy as follows:

- Go to *Control Panel > Internet Options*
- Switch to the *Connections* tab
- Click *LAN settings*
- Enable "Use a proxy server for your LAN"
- Enable "Bypass proxy server for local addresses"
- Click *Advanced*
- Disable "Use the same proxy server for all protocols"
- At "Socks", specify the server address and port of the SOCKS5 proxy
- Ensure that HTTP, Secure, and FTP are blank
- Click *OK > Apply*.

Note that you need to use a proxy of type SOCKS5, not just any proxy.

Comment: Will I use the same IP and port (given by my University) which I am also using in above picture. Because I did that but it did not work. (While there is no option to enter username password) how can it work without username password.

Comment: Some proxies do not ask for username & password up front. If the proxy you have does not do SOCKS5, all you can do is to contact the Uni people and ask if they have such a proxy.

Comment: Good answer! Looks like Windows can indeed proxify system-wirde traffic (not just HTTP) without having to use third-party software like ProxyCap, at least if the proxy doesn't require username/password. However, I had to enter the (same) proxy IP/port into all 4 fields (HTTP, Secure, FTP, SOCKS). Leaving everything blank except Socks makes browser traffic not work.